# When the passive is preferred to the active: "allow Bolt to be entered"

Tags: passive-voice

I read the following from the NYT article titled "Usain Bolt Is Still the World’s Fastest Man":

> He withdrew on July 1 from the final of the 100 at the Jamaican Olympic trials with a slight tear in his left hamstring muscle. But Jamaica’s rules, unlike those of the United States, which require a top-three finish to qualify for the Summer Games, **allowed Bolt to be entered in the Rio Games anyway.**

(http://www.nytimes.com/2016/08/15/sports/olympics/usain-bolt-100-meters-justin-gatlin-results.html?_r=0)

In the bold-faced part of the sentence, can anyone please explain to me why the author wrote "allowed Bolt ***to be entered***" instead of "allowed Bolt ***to enter***"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The passive there emphasizes the *country's* prerogative to enter an athlete in the games according to its own rules. It is not that the passive is "preferred" over the active.

Comment: This is very interesting. In my understanding of your explanation, "the country" is a hidden doer in the sentence: even though it is not explicitly expressed, the country is the one that decides which athlete can enter in the Olympics. Since this was the connotation the author tried to convey, passive tense was used. I am trying to come up with similar kinds of sentences: on the surface, active tense seems to make sense, but to emphasize the hidden doer, passive tense is used. If anyone can come up with an example, please reply to this.

Comment: The "hidden doer" is actually not so hidden; it is given a name.. "*Jamaica's* rules...allowed Bolt to be entered..."  Grammatically, the noun-phrase "Jamaica's rules" is the subject of the verb "allowed". A second country is mentioned, the United States, along with its method of qualifying, which also leaves the athlete out of the picture, grammatically speaking:  "a top-three finish *to qualify*...".   I think you will be able to comparable sentences in many domains, e.g. chess, sport, military, transport, messaging, and so on.

Comment: sorry, omitted word: able to *find*...

Answer (score 0):

The author is using

> to be entered

to mean "to attend as a participant"

> allowed Bolt to be entered in the Rio Games anyway
>   *allowed Bolt to participate in the Rio Games anyway*
>
> His name was entered on the roster.

since the author is explaining the difference in qualification rules.

To use

> to enter

would be more ambiguous since it could mean that Bolt attended the games but as a spectator, as in he "entered the stadium to watch".

Comment: "Enter in" vs. "enter" is what makes the difference in the connotations you mentioned. The equivalent phase would be "to enter in the Rio Games", which has the same connotation of registering/attending.  See, for example, definition #5 here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entered+into